# I don't want to have any boundaries when editing the uv

Tags: shaders

I used separate node to put eye image in the red part.

I used separate node to put eyebrows in the green area.

In the uv map, there's no boundary between the two.

If you look at the complete version, there are boundaries.

How can there be no boundary?

[image]

There's an orange border between the black ones.

[image]

There's no boundaries on the uv.

this is my file.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a slight amount of interpolation between black and white in the axis vectors you are using as your mix factor(s). Adding some ColorRamps set to constant with a rather tight cutoff (see the white value) to your mix factors seems to get rid of it:

[image: Gradient]

Comment: thank you very much it works